# android-studio : formatting dialog inserts unknown character

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10, code-formatting

I am using Android Studio on Windows 10. While formatting code, by pressing:

`ctrl` + `shift` + `alt` + `L`

It inserts some unknown character into code, along with showing formatting dialog as:

[image]

I tried to search in keymap but found nothing.

I have habit of frequently formatting the code. So, can someone help me get rid of this issue?

**PS:** I am using Android Studio 3.5, but this issue is bothering since Android Studio 3.0 was launched. Problem is not limited to XML, it also occurs in formatting Java/Kotlin code as well.